# Getting the following ADFS error for an SP initiated profile

Tags: stored-procedures, naming-conventions, adfs3.0

I understand that the `nameid` isn't being satisfied, I am not just not sure how to read this properly.

I have an SP initiated ADFS profile.

I keep getting the following error:

`Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.InvalidNameIdPolicyException: MSIS7070: The SAML request contained a NameIDPolicy that was not satisfied by the issued token. Requested NameIDPolicy: AllowCreate: False Format: urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient SPNameQualifier: . Actual NameID properties: Format: urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress, NameQualifier:  SPNameQualifier: , SPProvidedId: .`